# Cursor of form does not change

Tags: vb.net, cursor

Within a sub I check some values and open a MsgBox which pops up outside my form by default.
After closing the MsgBox, I want to change the cursor of the form to "Cursors.WaitCursor".
As after clicking "OK" in the MsgBox the mouse position is outside my form, I´d expect the form cursor to change to WaitCursor when I move the mouse into my form. But the cursor doesn´t change.

```
MsgBox()                          'is positioned outside the form by default
Application.DoEvents              
Me.Cursor=Cursors.WaitCursor      'After closing MsgBox, the form gets back the focus, so "Me" should
                                  'refer to the appropiate thread
Application.DoEvents

DoSomething for 20secs
Me.Cursor=Cursors.Default
```

Removing "Application.DoEvents" does not show any effect.
When I move the MsgBox opened into the form with the mouse and click "OK" the cursor of the form changes to WaitCursor as expected.

I do not want to set the cursor before I open the MsgBox (as pressing Cancel should exit the sub immediately, and I do not want to set the cursor back to default).
(I also do not want to position the MsgBox within my form)
Does anybody know what´s going on?
thx in advance.
Werner

Comment: Don't do something on the UI thread for 20 seconds in the first place. If you think that `Application.DoEvents` is a good idea then you're almost certainly trying to find a workaround for bad code. Just write good code in the first place. Either use multi-threading or the Tasks Parallel Library (TPL) with `Async`/`Await`.

Comment: @mie Another vote for using TPL, but I'd stay away from multithreading if I were you. Not wishing to sound harsh, but I think trying a multithreading solution will cause you more problems than it solves

Comment: @CaiusJard, that seems a fairly strange evaluation. Obviously `Tasks` can be used in ways that `Threads` previously wouldn't have been but, by the same token, any things that previously would have been done with `Threads`, either directly or via the `ThreadPool` or a `BackgroundWorker`, is now done with `Tasks`. You'd have to know what was actually being done to determine what might be the best option but a multithreading solution would almost certainly work well if implemented properly. The question is whether an inexperienced user can do that, but can they use the TPL effectively either?

Comment: I do agree, App.DoEvents are no good coding style. I added those just to make sure not to receive answers as "Add Application.DoEvents" ;-) and - as I mentioned, they show no effect.
The 20 s sub-task is a time consuming process to write data to a fairly slow I2C-smartcard. The user is not allowed or able to do anything with the program during this process so a waiting cursor seems appropiate to me.
What seems strange to me is, when the MsgBox (and the OK button as well) is placed outside my form, why can I not set the waiting cursor for the form after closing the MsgBox?